# Progress Dialog is not dismissing after the given delay any solution?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, progressdialog, progress

```
 btnUpdateEduInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            progressDialog.show();
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                public void run() {
                                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Something went wrong!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }, 1000);
        });
```

I want to show progress dialog when I save data in fire base and dismiss dialoq if data is not saved. I have used thread and handler but nothing works. any solution for this problem?

Comment: what is an error?

Comment: progress dialog is not dismissed!!!

Comment: after the given delay

Comment: I have checked with this Dialog is dismissing in my case

Comment: so what should be the problem on my side any suggestion?

Comment: May be the handler is not running try to print messsage in handler

Comment: ok I will try this

Answer (score 0):

You dissmiss dialog in worker thread so being this problem.
**Apply below solution**

```
 btnUpdateEduInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
        progressDialog.show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Something went wrong!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: if you satisfied with my answer then please accept ans and give a vote :)